# BLAS Matrix multiplication NaN

Tags: fortran, matrix-multiplication, lapack, blas, svd

I am performing an SVD of a matrix using the LAPACK library and then multiplying the matrices to double check that they are correct. See the code below

```
subroutine svd_and_dgemm() ! -- Matrix decomp: A = USV^t
  implicit none

  integer,parameter :: m = 2
  integer,parameter :: n = 3
  integer i,info,lda,ldu,ldv,lwork,l,lds,ldc,ldvt,ldd
  real*8 :: a(m,n),a_copy(m,n),sdiag(min(m,n)),s(m,n),u(m,m),vt(n,n),alpha,beta,c(m,n),d(m,n)
  character jobu, jobv, transu, transs
  real*8, allocatable, dimension ( : ) :: work

  lwork = max(1,3*min(m,n) + max(m,n), 5*min(m,n))
  allocate (work(lwork))

  a = reshape((/3,1,1,-1,3,1/),shape(a),order=(/2, 1/)) !column-wise
  print*,'A'
  print*, a(1,1), a(1,2), a(1,3)
  print*, a(2,1), a(2,2), a(2,3)

  jobu = 'A'
  jobv = 'A'
  lda = m
  ldu = m
  ldv = n
  a_copy = a

  call dgesvd (jobu, jobv, m, n, a_copy, lda, sdiag, u, ldu, vt, ldv, work, lwork, info)
  if ( info /= 0 ) then
    write ( *, '(a)' ) ' '
    write ( *, '(a)' ) 'R8MAT_SVD_LAPACK - Failure!'
    write ( *, '(a)' ) '  The SVD could not be calculated.'
    write ( *, '(a)' ) '  LAPACK routine DGESVD returned a nonzero'
    write ( *, '(a,i8)' ) '  value of the error flag, INFO = ', info
    return
  end if
!
!  Make the MxN matrix S from the diagonal values in SDIAG.
  s(1:m,1:n) = 0.0D+00
  do i = 1, min ( m, n )
    s(i,i) = sdiag(i)
  end do

  print*,'U'
  print*, u(1,1), u(1,2)
  print*, u(2,1), u(2,2)
  print*,'S'
  print*, s(1,1), s(1,2), s(1,3)
  print*, s(2,1), s(2,2), s(2,3)
  print*,'Vt'
  print*, vt(1,1), vt(1,2), vt(1,3)
  print*, vt(2,1), vt(2,2), vt(2,3)
  print*, vt(3,1), vt(3,2), vt(3,3)
  deallocate (work)

  ! -- Verify SVD: A = USV^t
  ! -- Compute C = US
  transu = 'N'
  transs = 'N'
  ldu = m;     lds = m;   ldc = m
  alpha = 1.;  beta = 1.
  call dgemm(transu,transs,m,n,m,alpha,u,ldu,s,lds,beta,c,ldc)
  ! -- Compute A = D = CV^t
  l = m ! nrows C
  ldvt = n;   ldd = m
  call dgemm(transu,transs,m,n,n,alpha,c,ldc,vt,ldvt,beta,d,ldd)
  print*,'C'
  print*, c(1,1), c(1,2), c(1,3)
  print*, c(2,1), c(2,2), c(2,3)
  print*,'D'
  print*, d(1,1), d(1,2), d(1,3)
  print*, d(2,1), d(2,2), d(2,3)    
end subroutine svd_and_dgemm
```

The output I get is

```
 A
   3.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000     
  -1.0000000000000000        3.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000     
 U
 -0.70710678118654835      -0.70710678118654657     
 -0.70710678118654668       0.70710678118654846     
 S
   3.4641016151377553        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000        3.1622776601683795        0.0000000000000000     
 Vt
 -0.40824829046386402      -0.81649658092772526      -0.40824829046386291     
 -0.89442719099991508       0.44721359549995882        5.2735593669694936E-016
 -0.18257418583505536      -0.36514837167011066       0.91287092917527679     
 C
  -2.4494897427831814       -2.2360679774997867        0.0000000000000000     
  -2.4494897427831757        2.2360679774997929        0.0000000000000000     
 D
   2.9999999999999991        1.0000000000000002       0.99999999999999989     
                       NaN   2.9999999999999991        1.0000000000000000
```

So I am not sure where is this NaN coming from. The odd thing is that if before printing D in such way I print it as follows:

```
  print*,'D'
  print*, d
```

Then I don't get the NaN anymore, so the output for D is

```
 D
   2.9999999999999991      -0.99999999999999933        1.0000000000000002        2.9999999999999991       0.99999999999999989        1.0000000000000000     
 D
   2.9999999999999991        1.0000000000000002       0.99999999999999989     
 -0.99999999999999933        2.9999999999999991        1.0000000000000000
```

Any idea why is this happening?

PS: Information for the [dgesvd](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFHY8_5.4.0/com.ibm.cluster.essl.v5r4.essl100.doc/am5gr_hgesvd.htm) (LAPACK) and [dgemm](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFHY8_5.2.0/com.ibm.cluster.essl.v5r2.essl100.doc/am5gr_hsgemm.htm) (BLAS) subroutines.

Comment: Which error checking compiler flags do you use? How do you compile it at all?

Comment: This is a subroutine within a big program, but basically looks like this: 
`gfortran -cpp  -Ofast -funroll-loops --param max-unroll-times=4  -o lotus lotus.o -L/home/bfg/Workspace/solver/oop/. -L/home/bfg/Workspace/solver/geom_lib/. -L/usr/lib/lapack/. -L/usr/lib/libblas/. -lfluid -lgeom -llapack -lblas`

Comment: As an update: I have compiled the subroutine in another test program that only contains this subroutine and now the NaN has disappeared. I used the same subroutine,  same compiler and flags. It's very weird!

Comment: Try to compile with `-fbounds-check` (checks for out of bounds array calls) or `-Wuninitialized` (checks for variables that are not initialized with a value before they are used). If that doesn't throw errors/warnings, check very carefully if the subroutines have the right arguments and if you can use them as you think you can (for example, twice `n` in `dgemm`).

Comment: Checking the previous flags and `-fcheck=all` I don't get any error. The thing is: why if I print D before printing it component by component the result changes?

Comment: If you read the best practice guide on fortran90.org, you might find that you are using some less stable way of doing something. And some unexpected memory access is happening. You might need to interface the dgemm subroutine or keep it in an isolated module. Did you try to initialize `d=0.0d0`?

Comment: @JonatanÖström I isolated the module and did not make any difference, but initializing the matrices first helped. If you add the answer I will accept it.Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with 'first helped', did it stop working again?

Comment: Aha, ye, you mean that first initializing them helped. I interpreted that wrong. Ok, nice, I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from our comments dialogue it seems like you have a problem that stems from not initializing an array. It is always good practice to do this, and in situations where you do operations like `var = var +1` it is required. If you are *unlucky* your program will work fine anyway. But then strange things happen once in a while when some garbage happened to reside in memory where the array gets allocated.

A double should be initialized like this

```
array = 0.0d0 ! for double precision
```

or

```
array = 0  ! ok for single,double and integer
```

Initialize single precision but *not* double precision like this:

```
array = 0.0 ! single (not double) precision.
```

or this

```
array = 0.0e0 ! single (not double) precision.
```

I recommend the page [fortran90.org](http://www.fortran90.org).

Comment: `array = 0` is completely sufficient in all cases above (as I have commented before at some other answer of yours).  The more complicated possibilities only hurt readability in this case. And it is not *allocation*, but *definition*.

Comment: Yes, allocation was wrong, I changed it to initialization. Regarding what form to use, it's a question of preference, so I gave all that i knew. I think there is a point to the longer versions, because they indicate what type the variable is.

Comment: BTW initialization is technically also wrong, but we understand the intended meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications @VladimirF